# Cannot create Pipiline in BlueOcean, it got stuck on connection to Bitbucket stage with no errors

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-blueocean

I am trying to create pipeline via BlueOcean, however creation got stuck at the connection stage despite there is no error on connection.

After choosing "Where is your Bitbucket Server?" and
Putting credentials to "Connect to Bitbucket" 
Pressing button "connect" see icon that it progressing for a second, but it do not progress to next step.
No error messages. Credentials are definitely correct, I had tested with wrong credentials and saw "Invalid username and/or password"

**Details for Bitbucket and Jenkins**
I have admin rights in both Bitbucket and Jenkins

**Bitbucket**
Installed v5.8.0 for testing new version on my desktop http://pc_name.company.com:7990
It seems working ok, I can add users, create repo, clone repo in jenkins

**Jenkins** 
ver. 2.89.3 as well installed at the same PC, working ok as well
Installed Blueocean plugin 1.4.2

Screenshot attached [link to screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzMXk.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck in a similar situation. I'm selecting "Bitbucket Cloud" as the selected repository.

I resolved my issue by giving full access to "Generate Password" option in my Bitbucket - in case it helps someone else

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate where you've found the "Generate Password" option in Bitbucket?